# Breeze is not deserializing entity change sets when saving changes

Tags: breeze

I am using Breeze against a standard RPC style WebAPI. I have decorated the controller with the `[BreezeController]` attribute. I have defined entity metadata on the client for the entities being returned by the WebAPI actions. My Breeze DataService is setup as follows:

```
var dataService = new breeze.DataService({
    serviceName: "http://localhost/api/PartReceiptPurchaseOrders",
    hasServerMetadata: false
});
```

When calling the EntityManager's `SaveChanges` method after modifying an entity, the `EntityInfo` object on the server is empty. It appears the serialized entity passed to the SaveChanges method is not being deserialized properly into the expected entity on the server. I'm having a hard time understanding what I'm doing wrong.

When I inspect the `JObject saveBundle` argument passed to the `SaveChanges` method on the WebAPI controller, I get the expected entity details:

```
{  
    "entities": [{ 
        "PurchaseOrderPartId": 1, 
        "PartNumber": "ABC", 
        "SupplierPartNumber": "12345", 
        "Description": "Some Part", 
        "Bin": "1", 
        "Qty": 24, 
        "QtyReceived": 24, 
        "QtyBackordered": 0, 
        "Cost": 60, 
        "Currency": "USD",
        "PurchaseOrderId":1, 
        "entityAspect": { 
            "entityTypeName": "PurchaseOrderPart:#MyApp.Models", 
            "entityState": "Modified",
            "originalValuesMap": { 
                "QtyReceived": 0 
            }, 
            "autoGeneratedKey":{
                "propertyName": "PurchaseOrderPartId",
                "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
            }
        }    
    }],  
    "saveOptions": { "allowConcurrentSaves": false }
}
```

However, after the call to the base class method `Breeze.WebApi.ContextProvider.SaveChanges()` the `entityInfo.Entity` property contains an empty object as follows:

```
entityInfo {Breeze.WebApi.EntityInfo}   
    AutoGeneratedKey: null {Breeze.WebApi.AutoGeneratedKey}
    Entity {MyApp.Models.PurchaseOrderPart}
        Bin: null
        Cost: 0
        Currency: null
        Description: null
        PartNumber: null
        PurchaseOrder: null {MyApp.Models.PurchaseOrder}
        PurchaseOrderId: 0
        PurchaseOrderPartId: 0
        Qty: 0
        QtyBackordered: 0
        QtyReceived: 0
        SupplierPartNumber: null
```

If I breakpoint into the `CreateEntityInfoFromJson` in the `Breeze.WebApi.ContextProvider` class, I see that the call to `jsonSerializer.Deserialize(new JTokenReader(jo), entityType)` sets `entityInfo.Entity` to an empty entity object. There is no error raised during the deserialization so I can't tell why this is happening.

Can anyone point me towards a possible resolution?

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out and it was a dumb mistake on my part. My entity type on the server had been declared with internal setters like `public decimal QtyReceived { get; **internal** set; }`. This meant the JSON deserializer couldn't set the property value. Interestingly enough, the error is just ignored by the deserilizer.

Changing the setters to be public fixed this issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting back.  This one would have killed me trying to repro it :)